# The external hard drive is not showing up

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive

The external hard drive is not showing up, even in the disk application.

Terminal output:

[image: Terminal output]

Laptop information:

[image: Laptop information]

It is properly working on another computer with Windows, also on this laptop the flash drive working properly. The hard drive does not work on any ports.

```
[ 3134.958371] audit: type=1107 audit(1653060613.100:82): pid=874 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=3434 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=888 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 3134.975039] audit: type=1107 audit(1653060613.116:83): pid=874 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=3434 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=888 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 3134.975184] audit: type=1107 audit(1653060613.116:84): pid=874 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=3434 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=888 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: Insert the disk and run `dmesg | tail`, then post the output to your question. Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Have you turned fast start up off in Windows? Otherwise it is hibernated and LInux NTFS driver will not default mount it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: If this is a USB drive, edit your question and show me `lsusb` when the drive is connected. Also, have you tried a different USB cable?

Comment: @Pilot6 It needs to be `sudo dmesg | tail`.

Comment: @heynnema No, why? `dmesg` doesn't require `sudo`.

Comment: @Pilot6 On recent versions of Ubuntu it certainly does... maybe not 20.04.

Comment: @heynnema You are correct. I am still using 20.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 Upgrade... you're two years behind the curve ball :-)

Comment: There are lots of bugs. I'll wait a bit. I have all kinds of releases in a VB.

Comment: @Pilot6 I first upgraded my two backup machines to 22.04, and then just a couple of days ago I upgraded my main machine. With the exception of it breaking my VPN, it seems stable, and few problems.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did have to jump through a few hoops to get rid of that stupid SNAP version of Firefox... and also get it to auto-update from the Mozilla repo.

Comment: @Pilot6 I pasted an output to this topic